# redis get multiple key's values that value is hash set in a single query?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

How do I get the value of multiple  key's that value is **hash set** in Redis(StackExchange.Redis)?

Code **database.HashGetAll("myhash")** get all keys values from key **myhash** and I want get list keys  myhash1 myhash2 from redis with good performance.

Comment: Redis doesn't have such built in feature, but with Redis pipeline you should get a good performance

Comment: Stackexchange api seems it does not support get **keys** at database level but it supports at connection level see the link below https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan once you have keys you can use pipeline to get all values for those keys